# I am unable to change the Screen through the Navigation Drawer in kivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am currently programming an app in which i want 3 screens that i can access through a Navigation Drawer. Every item is clickable in the Navigation Drawer but the Screen doesn't change. i implemented a method that is called when an item of the list is clicked which should change the screen but nothing happens

here is the code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (360, 750)

helpstring = """
<MyApp>:
    theme_cls: theme_cls
    screen_manager: screen_manager

Screen:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        Screen1:
        Screen2:
        Screen3:


    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: layout
            
            MDTopAppBar:
                type: 'top'
                title: ''
                left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state()]]
            Widget:                                                             # i added the widget for the Appbar to move to the top

    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'

    Screen3:
        name: 'screen3'
        

    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        orientation: 'vertical'
        elevation: 2
        MDScrollView:   
            MDList:
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    on_press: app.change_screen('screen1')
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'human-male'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    on_press: app.change_screen('screen2')
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'dog'

                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: "Screen 3"
                    on_press: app.change_screen('screen3')
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'cat'  



"""


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class Screen3(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
sm.add_widget(Screen3(name='screen3'))


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        bildschirm = Builder.load_string(helpstring)
        return bildschirm

    def change_screen(self, name):
        sm.current = name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Make sure that the indentations in `kvlang` are consistent with class design.

Comment: In your `change_screen()` method, you reference `sm`, but the `ScreenManager` that `sm` references is not part of your GUI. You have not actually used `sm`, and your entire GUI is defined by your `helpstring`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There a several issues with your code, including that mentioned in my comment above. But here is a modified version of your code that I think will do what you intended:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Window.size = (360, 750)

helpstring = """

# <MyApp>:  # Cannot use kv rules for an App class
#     theme_cls: theme_cls
#     screen_manager: screen_manager
    
<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen1'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: layout
        
        MDTopAppBar:
            type: 'top'
            title: ''
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: app.root.ids.nav_drawer.set_state()]]
        Widget:                                                             # i added the widget for the Appbar to move to the top

<Screen2>:
    name: 'screen2'
    Label:
        text: 'Screen2'
        color: 1,0,0,1

<Screen3>:
    name: 'screen3'
    Label:
        text: 'Screen3'
        color: 1,0,0,1
    


FloatLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager
        Screen1:
        Screen2:
        Screen3:


    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        orientation: 'vertical'
        elevation: 2
        MDScrollView:   
            MDList:
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: "Screen 1"
                    on_press: app.change_screen('screen1')
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'human-male'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: "Screen 2"
                    on_press: app.change_screen('screen2')
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'dog'

                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: "Screen 3"
                    on_press: app.change_screen('screen3')
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'cat'  


"""


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class Screen3(Screen):
    pass

# The code below is never used
# sm = ScreenManager()
# sm.add_widget(Screen1(name='screen1'))
# sm.add_widget(Screen2(name='screen2'))
# sm.add_widget(Screen3(name='screen3'))


class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        bildschirm = Builder.load_string(helpstring)
        return bildschirm

    def change_screen(self, name):
        self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = name


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```